# Expand/Collapse sidebar with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, redux, sidebar

I am new into **Redux** and I would like to know if this is the right approach how to implement **Expand/Collapse** sidebar with same button.

I have React component Sidebar with bool variable `isCollapsed` which initial state is `false` which means sidebar is expanded.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        sidebar: { isCollapsed: false }
    }

    this.onClickCollapseSidebar = this.onClickCollapseSidebar.bind(this)
}
```

And in `onClick` I am calling selfdefined method `onClickCollapseSidebar`

```
<a onClick={this.onClickCollapseSidebar}  className="sidebar-control"></a>
```

And inside `onClickCollapseSidebar` I am dispatching actions for collpase and expand.

```
onClickCollapseSidebar(event) {
    if(this.props.sidebar.isCollapsed) {
        this.props.actions.expandSidebar(this.props.sidebar)
    } else {
        this.props.actions.collapseSidebar(this.state.sidebar)
    }
}
```

And I want to know if this is correct approach how to handle those kind of situations with Redux.

I know that I can use local state with react's `setState` method or use library as [redux-ui](https://github.com/tonyhb/redux-ui) to handle those situation, but i would like to do it with redux only.

> My reducer for those actions is

```
export default function sidebarReducer(state = [], action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case types.COLLAPSE_SIDEBAR:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {isCollapsed: true})
    case types.EXPAND_SIDEBAR:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {isCollapsed: false})
    default:
        return state
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since redux maintains your sidebar state, you don't need to declare the state in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.onClickCollapseSidebar = this.onClickCollapseSidebar.bind(this)
}
```

You don't have to pass anything to the `expandSidebar()` and `collapseSidebar()` action creators, since your reducer uses the action type, and not the payload.

```
onClickCollapseSidebar(event) {
    if(this.props.sidebar.isCollapsed) {
        this.props.actions.expandSidebar()
    } else {
        this.props.actions.collapseSidebar()
    }
}
```

Define the initial state correctly - `state = {isCollapsed: false}`

```
export default function sidebarReducer(state = {isCollapsed: false}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case types.COLLAPSE_SIDEBAR:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {isCollapsed: true})
    case types.EXPAND_SIDEBAR:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {isCollapsed: false})
    default:
        return state
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it make sense.